# What is a Best way to handle Multi threading with callbacks in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, multi-tenant, coroutine, futuretask

I want to display multiple windows in a queue after some wait time. So what is the best way to implement the same?

1. ThreadPoolExecutor
2. FutureTask
3. Coroutines
   or any other way in Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

Coroutines would be my first choice.

```
launch {
    delay(1000)
    displayWindow()
}
```

Comment: What if I want to display multiple window?
Eg : on one event display window after 10 sec. After 5 sec I trigger another event which displays window after 5 sec. To avoid multiple windows I want a callback. So how can I solve this ?

Comment: To prevent multiple windows, create a singleton helper object for displaying popup window, with a property isShowing (for example) and handle new window displaying only if isShowing is set to false. Just an idea, there are multiple ways to achieve that.